# Конфигурация сетевой безопасности не разрешает доступ по HTTP

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Если подключить изображение по адресу, протокол которого **HTTPS**, то все работает нормально.

```
final String _path = 'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl-2.jpg';
```

Если подключить изображение по адресу, протокол которого **HTTP**, то все **НЕ** работает.

```
final String _path = 'http://fr38060s.bget.ru/_html/perform/img/car.jpg';
```

Раньше, эта проблема решалась так. В файле в теге **application** **AndroidManifest.xml** добавлялся атрибут

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Сейчас все по другому, если перейти по ссылке

[Network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted)

Я создал папку **xml** в папке **android/app/src/main/res**

Создал в ней файл **network-security-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
 <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

В **AndroidManifest.xml** добавил

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network-security-config"
```

далее, полный код

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.f1">

 <application
  android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network-security-config"
  android:name="${applicationName}"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:label="f1">
  <activity
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
   android:exported="true"
   android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
   android:launchMode="singleTop"
   android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
   <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
        the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
        while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
        to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
   <meta-data
    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
    android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
       This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
  <meta-data
   android:name="flutterEmbedding"
   android:value="2" />
 </application>
</manifest>
```

***main.dart***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: const Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: const SafeArea(
     child: MyHomePage(),
    ),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 //работает, потому что https
 //final String _path = 'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl-2.jpg';

 //не работает, потому что http
 final String _path = 'http://fr38060s.bget.ru/_html/perform/img/car.jpg';

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Align(
   alignment: Alignment.center,
   child: Image.network(
    _path,
    fit: BoxFit.contain,
    width: 300.0,
    height: 400.0,
   ),
  );
 }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня есть приложение аналогичное, все работает через network-security-config.xml

Comment: Уважаемый Style-7! Попробуйте вставить  путь моего изображения, если это возможно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял, теперь нужно перечислять домены к которым можно обращаться по **HTTP**:

**network-security-config.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">fr38060s.bget.ru</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">blablabla.com</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: Уважаемый Spatz! Огромное Вам спасибо, НО УВЫ, ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЕ НЕ ЗАГРУЖАЕТСЯ.

Answer (score 1):

Андроид проверяет конфигурацию перед отправкой запроса и выдаёт ошибку либо сразу, либо при коннекте к серверу.
У вас (судя по надписи на скрине) запрос прошёл успешно. Но сервер вернул код `403`.
То есть проблема на стороне сервера - ему не нравится запрос и он запретил доступ к файлу.
Пара тестов показала, что проблема в `User-Agent` - серверу не нравится дефолтный из андроида, подмена на строку от браузера исправляет ситуацию, но как подменить в вашем случае я без понятия - flutter не знаю (но наверняка там есть возможность задать заголовки запроса).
Возможно лучше поправить это на стороне сервера, иначе у сайта могут быть проблемы при просмотре с мобильника.

Comment: Уважаемый woesss! Огромное Вам спасибо!